# Smallest integer that is not a sum of three or fewer elements of a prime set (with replacement)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, contest-math

I came across this problem today.

> In the game of primes, players roll a fair cube whose faces are labeled $2$, $3$, $5$, $7$, $11$ and $13$. What is the smallest integer sum greater than $2$ that cannot be made by rolling the die once, twice or three times?

The answer is fairly easy to get just by testing each positive integer up to $30$ and realizing it doesn't work, but I was wondering if there was something faster or more elegant.

This is the only information I could find about this problem online:
https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c50h436842

Comment: I guess I would first describe all the numbers that can be reached by two tosses, that's pretty easy.  Then you just need to add each of the $6$ values to that list to get the values that can be reached by three tosses.  Or, just look at the gaps in the list you get with one and two tosses, and see which of those you can fill with a third toss.

Comment: I don't think there's anything significantly easier. However, if you use generating functions, then the computation reduces to expanding $(1+x^2+x^3+x^5+x^7+x^{11}+x^{13})^3$ and looking for the smallest power of $x$ (other than $x^1$) that doesn't appear.